# Understanding Teradata sample qstart scripts

Tags: teradata

I'm new to Teradata so trying to understand the sample/qstart programs in the Teradata dir. I was looking into the qstart1, and didn't understand where definition of the `OPERATOR "$FILE_WRITER"` or `"$LOAD"` was.

Can some one please help me with that.

Answer (score 1):

You mean the scripts found in Teradata\Client...? Those are examples for TPT (Teradata Parallel Transporter).

Files in `quickstart` are based on the *TPT Quick Start Guide* and `userguide` scripts are based on the *TPT User Guide*.

Download those PDFs matching your TPT version at [info.teradata.com](http://www.info.teradata.com/templates/eSrchResults.cfm?txtpid=&txtttlkywrd=TBUILD&txtrelno=&prodline=&nm=Teradata%20Parallel%20Transporter&srtord=Desc&rdSort=Date).

Comment: Thanks for the update. I looked into the quick start guide, but I could find the definition of OPERATOR($FILE_READER). Is this operator predefined or am I missing something/